# Mysql kubernetes pod aborts execution - CrashLoopbackOff

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I have a master node and a worker node. I'm running a yaml for mysql with pv/pvc/persistant volume claims. The log shows that mysql finds(every time it restarts)the previous directory where the database is being kept(for persistance). And even if i delete the files/directory /var/lib/mysql, the mysql server still detects it somehow.
Here's the log:

```
] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) initializing of server in progress as process 10
2023-06-29T16:30:30.612865Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2023-06-29T16:30:30.612875Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2023-06-29T16:30:30.614055Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

I tried `--ignore-db-dir=lost+found` and `fsGgroup: 1000` because I found on Google those solutions, but they didn't work for me. Here's my yaml file:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 10000
      tolerations:
        - key: "app"
          operator: "Equal"
          value: "mysql"
          effect: "NoSchedule"
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:latest
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: mypassword
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          args:
            - --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
            - "--ignore-db-dir=lost+found"
            - --initialize
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-pv
        - name: mysql-data
          emptyDir: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by checking line-by-line the yaml manifest and reducing the config to the following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql-pod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                  name: app-mysql-secret
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-pvc
```